# If isospin is conserved under strong interactions why it is represented by SU(2)?

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, group-representations, strong-force, isospin-symmetry

As far as I know from my readings SU(2) is a representation group of [isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) symmetry which shows deep symmetry of the strong force which conserves flavor.

Isospin symmetry is broken under weak interactions. On the other hand, [Standard Model](http://www.superstringtheory.com/experm/exper2a.html) is assumed to have SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) symmetry which here, SU(2) refers weak interaction. So if it refers weak interactions and isospin not conserved, why it is represented with SU(2) group? What is conserved rather than flavor now? I'm sure I misunderstand something please help me figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Strong) $SU(2)_F$ [isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) is a global $u\leftrightarrow d$ [flavor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_%28particle_physics%29) symmetry of the strong force (but not a symmetry of the EM force, and hence only an approximate symmetry).

The $SU(2)_F$ sits inside an approximate global $SU(3)_F$ flavor symmetry of the $u$, $d$ and $s$ quark, cf. e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_%28physics%29) Wikipedia page.

(Strong) isospin is different from the [weak isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin) and the standard model gauge group $SU(3)_C\times SU(2) \times U(1)$.

Comment: So these are totally different representations? gauge group has 3 generators which represents two W and Z bosons, isospin symmetry group SU(2) generators Pauli spin matrices? Is it about local and global symmetries, why they are all SU(2)? To make my life harder?

Comment: I updated the answer.